# System vs integrated system?

Tags: meaning

Sometimes the word "integrated" is put before system. According to google, is 'a set of things working together as parts of a mechanism or an interconnecting network', so isn't it integrated by definition?

Comment: What's the difference between a "circuit" and an "integrated circuit"?

Comment: Doesn't the context matter?  One system could be independent of another.  Please take a moment to take the [tour] and read the [FAQ] as you tailor your question.

Comment: I would suggest that an 'integrated system' is defined in opposition to a 'distributed system'. In terms of the Google definition that 'a set of things working together as part of a network' is an integrated system but 'a set of things working together as part of an interconnecting network' may be a distributed system if the network is widespread or only loosely linked.